# Как создать правильный стиль для блока на css?

Tags: html, css

У меня есль следующий код:

```
<table>
<td>
    <div class="block">
        <p>Welcome to the social network brings together people from different social strata. You can fast and free to register your profile and start chatting.</p>
    </div>
</td>
</table>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он был на расстоянии справа 600 px слева 200 px и при уменьшении размеров окна браузера текст не сужался?

Comment: Задайте фиксированную ширину и отступы слева и справа. Либо у .block задайте минимальную ширину.

Comment: > при уменьшении размеров окна браузера текст не сужался

Что простите? Вы может имели в виду перенос слов? 

Answer (score 5):

```
.block { padding: 0px 600px 0px 200px; }
.block p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:100%; }
```

Видимо, так. Плюс таблице либо **.block p** задать фиксированный размер.